# Longest sequence of sum of distinct squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, sums-of-squares

I want to find longest sequence of distinct squares that $\alpha_{_1}$ + ... + $\alpha_{_n}$ is given number.
In particular I want to find largest square in that sequence.

I've tried use Lagrange's four-square theorem, and then Fermat's theorem on biggest squares, but it it's not correct solution.

Please help me.
Sorry for my poor English. :)

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? A relevant paper is http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa67/aa6745.pdf.

Comment: @RichardStanley, probably because the wording closely resembles the homework questions on MSE; something assigned rather than happened upon.

Comment: Using $1^2, \cdots, 20^2$ you can get every number from $129$ to $2741.$ So for a really big sum you could do pretty well by greedily take away squares of numbers from  $21,\cdots$ to try to get a remainder in this range and then finish off. That could at least give you a bound. Using just $1,\cdots,10$ gives everything from $129$ to $256$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about squares of positive integers (of course you can always include $0$ if you prefer, increasing the length by $1$). 
Let $F(n)$ be the 
length of the longest sequence representing $n$, or $-\infty$ if there is no such sequence.  Finding $F(n)$  can be viewed as a 
type of knapsack problem: if $k = \lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$,

maximize $\sum_{j=1}^k x_j$

subject to
$\sum_{j=1}^k j^2 x_j = n$

all $x_j \in \{0,1\}$

We therefore have a pseudo-polynomial dynamic programming algorithm. 
Let 
$A(n, j)$ be the length of the longest sequence representing $n$ using 
distinct squares of integers $\le j$, or $0$ if there is no such sequence.
Then $F(n) = A(n, \lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor)$, and
$$ \eqalign{A(0, j) &= 0 \cr
A(n,j) &= -\infty \ \text{if}\ n > \sum_{k=1}^j k^2\cr
A(n,j) &= A(n, j-1) \ \text{if}\ n < j^2\cr
A(n, j) &= \max(A(n,j-1), 1 + A(n-j^2, j-1))\ \text{otherwise}}$$